# Why does the Z80 not have EX DE, IX?

Tags: z80, instruction-set

Reading [Decoding Z80 Opcodes](http://z80.info/decoding.htm), There's a section about the `0xDD` prefix. This instruction prefix causes the next instruction to use the `IX` register instead of the `HL` register. That makes sense. `HL` and `IX` (also `IY`) are designed for holding pointers. That's why there's such an efficient encoding for `(HL)` (called `M` in Intel's parlance). This question is also about the `0xFD` instruction prefix which does the same but for `IY`.

Anyway, there's this comment about prefix `0xDD` in particular:

> If the next opcode makes use of HL, H, L, but not (HL), any occurrence of these will be replaced by IX, IXH, IXL respectively. An exception of this is EX DE, HL which is unaffected.

I think it's weird that `EX DE, HL` is unaffected by this instruction prefix. I can see the utility of being able to efficiently switch pointers around. So has this been "special-cased" somehow to remove the possibility of exchange `DE` with the index registers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply because these registers are not exchanged, but renamed (*1).

All `EX DE,HL` does is toggle a flip-flop which decides which is HL and which is DE.

Much the same way the exchange for alternate AF (`EX AF,AF'`) or alternate register (`EXX`) set is done. It's also the reason why all of them can be done in just 4 cycles — toggling either flip-flop does not need any data transfer.

---

*1 - I have a vague feeling I did already explain that as part of some question about the register set, but can't find it right now.

Comment: Your answer implies there is no hardware provision for renaming DE to IX

Comment: Of course not, that would be overly complex. each EX variation controls a single FF - including a double rename would require 3 of them just for DE/HL/IX and result in an undefined state at power up. Way overkill for a function just to be added to make some instruction set symmetry - if that would be one intended at all, since  the prefix is about replacing a source/destination register in a transfer, but EX does not do any transfer.

Comment: Hmmm... does EXX bring back the previous state of the DE/HL flip-flop as well then?

Comment: @TeaRex Each set has it's own FF

Comment: You may consult Ken Shirrif's blog entry on the implementation of the Z80 register. It goes down to the level of the transistor but at the beginning he explains it in a overview mode which might clarify how the flip-flops Raffzahn mentioned function.
One thing to get from that article is that the physical layout of the registers does not reflect the register overview one gets in assembly tutorials. The physical layout explains what operation are possible and why.
http://www.righto.com/2014/10/how-z80s-registers-are-implemented-down.html

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter: I wonder how the cost of the DE/HL latch compares with what it would have cost to output DE and input WZ during the first cycle of the instruction following an "ex de,hl", then output HL and input DE, then output WZ and input HL?  Given the split bus design, I think all three parts of the exchange could take place during the opcode fetch and "refresh" cycle, and the approach would have been easily extensible to add a two-byte 16-bit register move that could operate on prime as well as "ordinary" registers.